# Static UITableViewCell blank - Swift, iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am trying to implement some static cells in a `UITableView` using Xcode 6 beta 2 and Swift. I have successfully implemented dynamic cells.

When the user clicks on one of the dynamic cells there is a push segue to a new `UITableViewController` for a `UITableView` with static cells.

I have set this all up in Xcode and the segue works but when I drag a UILabel onto one of the static cells it just doesn't show up at run time. A few things that might help narrow down whats going on:

1. The data source methods are not being implemented in the `UITableViewController`
2. If I set the background of one of the static cells to a particular color, that shows up at run time

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The background color shows up but not the label?? Are you sure you're adding it to the correct subview? And are you setting the color in IB or code? That sounds weird.

Comment: That's correct - yes, weird! Can confirm that UILabel is added to the cell view. Setting color via IB. Tried UIButton too.. no luck.

Comment: You're probably clearing the layout or resetting the content view somewhere. Code would help diagnose it.

Comment: I would post code but there's practically no relevant code to post. In my 1st UITableViewController, I call `performSegueWithIdentifier` on table cell click. This then performs a `show (push)` segue to the 2nd UITableView. In the 2nd UITableViewController, I simply have the default file that Xcode sets up with all the datasource methods removed. Leaving only `init`, `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` - all of which have no customisation

Comment: Why do you have two UITableViewControllers?

Comment: For the 2 UITableViews - tap a cell on 1st UITableView, transitions to a more detailed 2nd UITableView

Comment: have you solved this issue? I have a similar problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the issue creating a new storyboard...

On a clean project it was working, maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24708004/3827274

TLDR:  it's an Xcode bug with changing the view to 'compact' width which seems to only affect alignment/positioning.  Click on your UILabel inside the cell and go to the inspector all the way to the bottom and play with the 'Installed' or note if the default one is disabled.