# Static UITableView not showing cells with subviews (UIButton, UISlider etc.) in Content View

Tags: xcode, uitableview, static, swift, popover

I've run into a peculiar problem with Xcode. I have a custom UITableViewController that appears as a popover for a few settings in an iPad app. It's a static table view with just 3 cells in 2 sections. It looks fine in the Storyboard editor, but at runtime the cells with custom views (UILabels, UISlider, UIButton) do not show up at all, but those custom views do (in random places).

When I delete the custom elements from the cell or change the cell to anything but custom then they show up fine, even if the view (like basic for example) contains a label in its Content View. It's a lot clearer to see with the attached picture.

To solve this, I've created a completely empty cell below those with custom elements. It looks fine, but I can't interact with any elements. User Interaction is enabled for all elements, cells, and the entire table view. If you have any ideas how to solve that or how to get the cells working properly so I don't need the blank cell hack that'd be much appreciated!

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 7 on OS X Yosemite, programming in Swift.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Storyboard & Simulator Screens]

Comment: I face the same issue with Xcode 6 Beta 7 on Mavericks. Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371954/static-uitableviewcell-blank-swift-ios-8

Comment: This issued was fixed with the GM Release of XCode 6. - Sep 9 (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered here [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666504/overlapping-cells-in-static-tableview-built-using-storyboard) Setting up **Auto Layout connections** from the label to the Content View solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of the above link as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421702/ios-swift-uitableviewcell-custom-subclass-not-displaying-content/24708004#24708004) one that finally solved it.

I added the 4 constraints from each object (UIButton and UISlider) to all four sides of its cell's Content View (top, bottom, leading, trailing). Then, I had to check the "installed" checkbox for each *constraint*, which was not checked.

Thank you so much for your help, it's working great now!